# Stationary process of a generalized closed Jackson network

Tags: queueing-theory

We have a generalized closed Jackson network where $\mu_i(n)=\frac{G(n-e_i)}{F(n)}$

How can I prove that the stationary process is given by the following formula: $$p_n=Β_mF(n)\prod\limits_ {i=1} ^{N}\lambda_i^{n_i}$$
Here $B_m$ is constant, $\lambda_i$ is the overall arrival rate for the $i$-th queue, $N$ is the number of queues, $n_i$ is the number of people in the $i$-th queue.

Comment: You should look at the Gordon-Newell theorem.